# Equivalent for loop complex condition

Tags: swift

I have code currently in my iOS project that looks like this:

```
for var i = 0; CGFloat(i) * gridSpacing.width * scale < bounds.width; ++i
```

I am now receiving warnings that this style for loop will be deprecated. Everywhere I look on Stack Overflow and elsewhere suggests using stride for complex for loops. However, stride doesn't help me here, as the end condition is not a simple comparison to another integer.

How do I do this in swift with a for-in loop?

Note, I could loop a CGFloat, but I want to avoid the incremental error by repeatedly adding floats.

I could also use a while loop, but I have several of these loops in the same function, and for creates a nice new scope for i. Swift doesn't seem to like arbitrary new scopes.

Edit: based on @Sulthan's answer, I created a SequenceType to do this. IMO, something like this should be in swift if for loops are being removed:

```
struct forgenerator : GeneratorType
{
    typealias Element = Int
    typealias Condition = (Element) -> Bool
    var idx : Element
    var condition : Condition
    var increment: Element

    mutating func next() -> Element? {
        if condition(idx)
        {
            let result = idx
            idx += increment
            return result
        }

        return nil
    }
}

struct forsequence : SequenceType
{
    typealias Generator = forgenerator
    var startPoint : Generator.Element
    var condition : Generator.Condition
    var increment : Generator.Element

    func generate() -> Generator {
        return forgenerator(idx: startPoint, condition: condition, increment: increment)
    }
}


func forgen(start: Int, condition: (Int) -> Bool, increment: Int) -> forsequence
{
    return forsequence(startPoint: start, condition: condition, increment: increment)
}

func forgen(start: Int, condition: (Int) -> Bool) -> forsequence
{
    return forgen(start, condition: condition, increment: 1)
}
```

Usage:

```
for i in forgen(0, condition: { CGFloat($0) * self.gridSpacing.width * self.scale < self.bounds.width})
```

Note, had to use self here everywhere because all those vars were members of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's go in steps:

```
let itemWidth = gridSpacing.width * scale
for var i = 0; CGFloat(i) < bounds.width / itemWidth; ++i {
}
```

Now you can directly

```
let itemWidth = gridSpacing.width * scale
let numItems = Int(floor(Double(bounds.width / itemWidth)))

for var i = 0; i < numItems; i++ {
}
```

or

```
for i in 0..<numItems {
}
```

Another option is to use `while` loop:

(I have used the solution you want to avoid but I feel it's still better and it's unlikely the error will be more important than the error introduced by `scale`).

```
let itemWidth = gridSpacing.width * scale
var x = 0
var index = 0

while (x < bounds.width) {
  // do something

  index += 1
  x += itemWidth
}
```

Also, you can always extract the iteration into a function:

```
func strideOverFloats(start: Int, addition: Int, condition: (CGFloat) -> Bool, _ closure: (Int) -> ()) {
    var i = start

    while (condition(CGFloat(i))) {
        closure(i)        
        i += addition
    }
}

let width: CGFloat = 200
let gridSize: CGFloat = 10
let scale: CGFloat = 2

strideOverFloats(0, addition: 1, condition: { $0 * gridSize * scale < width}) {
    print($0)
}
```

Comment: This is probably the closest to an answer, but I'm not in love with backing into the end condition. The original condition is much more straightforward to understand. Is there a higher-level construct that iterates a value until an arbitrary end condition is met?

Comment: @StevenSchveighoffer That's exactly what `while` loop does. You could also extract that functionality into a function that will take a closure to execute for every iteration. Or, if you want a more abstract solution, create your own Stridable.

Comment: right, I can switch to a while loop, but then the variable declarations have to be made outside the loop scope (a handy feature of for, considering swift doesn't allow arbitrary scopes). What I'm looking for is something like stride, but that allows an arbitrary end condition instead of an end point.

Comment: @StevenSchveighoffer I have added an example how you could extract `while` into a function, thus you won't be polluting your scope by variables.

Comment: Thanks, that is closer. I will see if I can make a generator in a similar fashion to use with for-in.

Comment: figured out a SequenceType generator, see question update.

Comment: Please also see below.. I think the where clause will help with what you're trying to accomplish in a Swift-y way.

Answer (score 1):

There's always recursion! Avoids while loops while still allowing you to deal with changing constraints. And it's functional! ;-)

```
func recursion(currentIndex: Int) {
    guard CGFloat(currentIndex) * gridSpacing.width * scale < bounds.width else {
        return
    }
    // do what you need to
    recursion(currentIndex + 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a `while` loop?

```
var i: CGFloat = 0
while ((i * gridSpacing.width * scale) < bounds.width) {
    // ...
    i += 1;
}
```

Comment: As I said, I have many of these loops in the same scope, so 'i' would have to be redeclared. Swift doesn't have arbitrary scopes as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a while loop:

```
var i: Int = 0

while CGFloat(i) * a * b < bounds.width {
    // Your code
    i += 1 // ++ is also deprecated
}
```

I think their intention is that `for-in` is used when the number of times being executed is known and `while` when it's conditional on variables that can be modified within the loop.

You could also use a conditional break statement within the `for-in` but the `while` seems cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest more swift style one:

```
for index in 0..<gridSpacing.width * scale {
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that for-in loops have a `where` clause!!

An example of the usage:

```
var end: CGFloat = bounds.width

for i in 0..<(Int(end+1)) where CGFloat(i) * gridSpacing.width * scale < CGFloat(end) {
    print(i)
}
```

Comment: How to define end? Can you just say infinity? Edit: I suppose I could say Int.max. But I really don't think this is what I want. Won't this go through all possible Ints in a loop even if it only executes the body 2x?

Comment: You can use something like CGFloat.max if you would like, but this should be your bounds.width.
I modified the solution to be closer to your example (couldn't enter some of those values in the Swift playground I was using, so it's unverified)